# How to reverse the order of a legend when using stackplot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a stackplot using python, and would like the legend at right to show the correct order of the colours - i.e I need to reverse it. However, when you reverse it, it also reverses the colours, meaning that the colours in the plot no longer correspond with the colours in the legend.

The code I have is as follows;

```
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as mplcm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset


    # ZOOM PLOT START AND END
    start = 408
    end = 518

    NUM_COLORS = 10

    cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_ncar')
    cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=NUM_COLORS-1)
    scalarMap = mplcm.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=cm)
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    # old way:
    ax.set_prop_cycle(color=[cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])

    # new way:
    #    ax.set_prop_cycle([scalarMap.to_rgba(i) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])
    ax.stackplot(range(0, 672), gen_type_summary[0,range1:range2], baseline="zero", linewidth=0.1)    
    ax.stackplot(range(0 , 672),  gen_type_summary[1:12,range1:range2], baseline="zero", linewidth=0.1)

    plt.axis([0,672, -5000,95000])
    plt.legend(gen_label[0:11], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
    plt.xlabel('Hours')
    plt.ylabel('Dispatch Level (MW)')
    fig.dpi = 1600
    fig.set_size_inches(w=16,h=5)
```

Unfortunately the stackoverflow image uploader isn't working to showcase the image. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The code isn't runnable. See [mcve]. Also, everyone would benefit from an image of the issue, so you may try again (sometimes it will not work for a couple of minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have the required dataset to run and work around with your code. I would require " gen_type_summary" and " gen_type_summary".
However, i can suggest you the store the legend handles and labels, reverse them and manually specify them in the plot legend. 
Something like this

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()   #get the handles
ax.legend(reversed(handles), reversed(labels))
```

In your case it would be rather simple

```
plt.legend(reversed(gen_label[0:11]), loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```